# Inconsistent query performance on same set of data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one JavaScript stored procedure in Snowflake which has three main queries.

1. The first query is a select query which have round 500 rows in output. The tables used in this select query, have master data which does not change frequently.
2. Then I have a while loop which creates a JSON from the previous query output.
3. Third query is also a select query.

**Sample code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_test_json_data()
RETURNS variant
LANGUAGE javascript
strict
EXECUTE AS caller
AS
$$
sample_result = snowflake.createStatement (
    {sqlText: "select col1, col2, arrat_agg(t2.json_data) JSON_DATA from tab1 t1 inner join tab2 t2 on t1.child_id = t2.id group by  col1, col2;"}).execute();

    agg_output = {};
    while(sample_result.next()){
        agg_output[sample_result.col1] = sample_result.JSON_DATA;   
    }
    
    sample_data = snowflake.createStatement ({sqlText: "Select .....;"}).execute();
    
    return agg_output;
$$;
```

In query history, I can see that the query start time of the first and third query has a difference of around 1 second usually, but in a few instances (3-4 times), the difference between the start time of the first and third query was close to 1 minute.

I have a few questions on this

- As data from first query is not changing, why we are seeing this inconsistent behavior?
- Is there any way to see while loop start time and end time in query history?
- Is this performance issue could be due to external factors like queuing or server load?

Comment: You are not running on a deterministic platform.  Even if your set of instructions could complete in a given time under ideal conditions, there are many other processes on the same system vying for resources.  In addition, where and how your data (or a portion thereof) is stored may cause differences due to what is and is not cached.

Comment: I've seen similar performance issues JS stored procedures with zero resource contention. Try a Python stored procedure and see if that helps.